# Complex json to java jackson

Tags: java

Here is my JSON, I want to convert into JAVA class

```
{
  "RELEASED": [
    {
      "purchaseOrderId": "2000",
      "date": "13/06/2019",
      "purchaseOrderLineId": "1",
      "itemCategory": "KuchItemCate1",
      "isDeliveryDelay": true,
      "isShipmentDelay": false
    }
  ],
  "SHIPPED": [
    {
      "purchaseOrderId": "1000",
      "date": "13/06/2019",
      "purchaseOrderLineId": "0",
      "itemCategory": "KuchItemCate0",
      "isDeliveryDelay": true,
      "isShipmentDelay": false
    },
    {
      "purchaseOrderId": "1000",
      "date": "13/06/2019",
      "purchaseOrderLineId": "2",
      "itemCategory": "KuchItemCate2",
      "isDeliveryDelay": true,
      "isShipmentDelay": false
    }
  ]
}
```

java Root class:MTHVendorPerformance

```
public class MTHVendorPerformance implements Serializable {
    Map<String,List<MTHPOStatusDetails>> stringListMap;

    public Map<String, List<MTHPOStatusDetails>> getStringListMap() {
        return stringListMap;
    }

    public void setStringListMap(Map<String, List<MTHPOStatusDetails>> stringListMap) {
        this.stringListMap = stringListMap;
    }
    /*@JsonProperty("RELEASED")
    private List<MTHPOStatusDetails> released;
    @JsonProperty("SHIPPED")
    private List<MTHPOStatusDetails> shipped;

    public List<MTHPOStatusDetails> getShipped() {
        return shipped;
    }

    public void setShipped(List<MTHPOStatusDetails> shipped) {
        this.shipped = shipped;
    }

    public List<MTHPOStatusDetails> getReleased() {
        return released;
    }

    public void setReleased(List<MTHPOStatusDetails> released) {
        this.released = released;
    }*/
}
```

Java Inner class:MTHPOStatusDetails

```
public class MTHPOStatusDetails {
    private String purchaseOrderId;
    private String date;
    private String purchaseOrderLineId;
    private String itemCategory;
    private boolean isDeliveryDelay;
    private boolean isShipmentDelay;

    public String getPurchaseOrderId() {
        return purchaseOrderId;
    }

    public void setPurchaseOrderId(String purchaseOrderId) {
        this.purchaseOrderId = purchaseOrderId;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getPurchaseOrderLineId() {
        return purchaseOrderLineId;
    }

    public void setPurchaseOrderLineId(String purchaseOrderLineId) {
        this.purchaseOrderLineId = purchaseOrderLineId;
    }

    public String getItemCategory() {
        return itemCategory;
    }

    public void setItemCategory(String itemCategory) {
        this.itemCategory = itemCategory;
    }

    public boolean isDeliveryDelay() {
        return isDeliveryDelay;
    }

    public void setDeliveryDelay(boolean deliveryDelay) {
        isDeliveryDelay = deliveryDelay;
    }

    public boolean isShipmentDelay() {
        return isShipmentDelay;
    }

    public void setShipmentDelay(boolean shipmentDelay) {
        isShipmentDelay = shipmentDelay;
    }
}
```

Code for convert JSON to java object

code snippet:::::::::

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
JsonObject jsonObject = ConfigReader.getConfigFromClasspath("vendor_performance_mth_data.json");

mthVendorPerformance = mapper.readValue(jsonObject.toString(),MTHVendorPerformance.class);
```

After running above code I am getting below exception. So please let me know in case if you have this kind of issues

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of com.samsclub.fidal.data.model.vendorperformance.MTHPOStatusDetails out of START_ARRAY token
     at [Source: (String)"{"RELEASED":
```

Comment: I am getting below error::

Comment: Why is the "RELEASED" json property commented out?

Comment: Becoz that way I need to check each status in our code. I want something which is dynamic. just ignore that part.
could you tell me what is the best way to convert below above mention json

Answer (score 2):

Get and set prefixes are missing in getters and setters for isDeliveryDelay and isShipmentDelay, should be getIsDeliveryDelay() setIsDeliveryDelay(...)
I think that you shadowing it by DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES.

If you want to have it stored in the map, you need to use: @JsonAnyGetter and @JsonAnySetter
something like this:

```
public static class MTHVendorPerformance {
    private Map<String, List<MTHPOStatusDetails>> fields = new HashMap<>();

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, List<MTHPOStatusDetails>> getFields() {
      return fields;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setFields(String key, List<MTHPOStatusDetails> value) {
      fields.put(key, value);
    }
  }
```